# Jquery closest() doesn't work on elements within different div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to use `closest()` to get `<input>` element which is in different div. Here's the markup:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span8">
        <input type="text" disabled="disabled" id="image-name">
    </div>
    <div class="span4">
        <input type="file">
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input:file").change(function (){
       var fileName = $(this).val();
       //Put the file name inside the disabled <input>
       $(this).closest('input:disabled').val(fileName);
    });
});
```

It doesn't do anything though. I tried changing `input:disabled` to `#image-name` but still doesn't work.

Any solution?

Thanks

Comment: One solution is to read documentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have an id on the other INPUT element, why are you using the closest function? Why not just $('#image-name')? The closest method does not work the way you think. closest always goes up the DOM tree until it finds a match.

Based on the comment to my initial suggestion, you could get DRY by using the more fancy versions of the jQuery event binders:

```
function handler(e, args) {
    $(e.data.elem).val(fileName);
}

$('input:file').bind('change', { elem: '#image-name' }, handler);
$('#other-input').bind('change', { elem: '#other-field' }, handler);
```

reusable event handler parameterized using event data constructs.

Comment: Well, because in other form it has two upload: Image and PDF. Both has similar markup and I don't want to duplicate the code. Thanks for the input.

Comment: Ah, I see, I've updated my post to give a suggestion for this. Might be useful.

Comment: **EDIT** Thanks, your new suggestion works perfect for keeping DRY code.

Comment: Not exactly sure what you are trying to do, or what the structure of your page is, but you can pass in any JS object into e.data via the second parameter and use it however you want.

Answer (score 1):

Because `closest` travels upwards, not sideways. Just to add, it starts matching the current element as well.

A more generic way is to use `closest` to find the common ancestor, which is `.row`, and `find` the disabled text box from there. You could also do `parent`, `prev` and `children`, assuming the HTML is always that way.

Comment: Thanks, great to know this

Answer (score 1):

Use `closest` to get to the root parent , then use find.

```
$(this).closest('.row').find('input[disabled]').val(fileName);
```

#### [Try this](http://jsfiddle.net/ZbPgv/)

Just now noticed your input has ID so you could just do `$('#image-name').val(fileName)`

Comment: Thanks, this one works perfectly. **EDIT**: In my other form, I have Upload PDF with similar markup but different ID. So your first answer works great.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
$(this).closest('.row').find('input:disabled').val(fileName);
```

since `closest()` will traverse up through its ancestors in the DOM tree.

Comment: Thanks, I always thought that `closest()` will find the nearest-written markup in the code.

Comment: @DarcCode Glad that you learn something new. Btw, you should use the suggestion of @syazdani since it's better when you've already given your `input` an `id`